# How to create usage plan with aws-sdk-apigateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to create a usage plan with aws-sdk apigateway, but getting an error response.

Here is the function I am using:

```
const params = {
    name: 'My usage plan',
    description: 'My plan for checking the usage',
    apiStages: [
      {
        apiId: 'b3mzhze48g',
        stage: 'dev',
        throttle: {
          string: {
            burstLimit: 4,
            rateLimit: 8,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    throttle: {
      burstLimit: 5,
      rateLimit: 10,
    },
    quota: {
      limit: 100,
      offset: 1,
      period: 'WEEK',
    },
  };
  try {
    const result = await apigateway.createUsagePlan(params).promise();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
```

here is an image of the id's I have for my API:

[api-ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cV3P.png)

and this is the error message I get:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid method {resourcePath: string,method: } specified",
    "code": "BadRequestException",
    "time": "2021-01-31T10:58:28.117Z",
    "requestId": "6d175534-e555-4a0d-99ef-1f3fc628e502",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 80.40030962554764
}
```

How should I modify the apiStages parameters to be able to set the usage plan for a specific resource in my API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with apiStages -> throttle, it is used to throttle at resource & method level, It is optional, But if it is set, key should be resource + method name , i.e. for GET /staff/list method , /staff/list/GET should be key

```
apiStages: [
    {
      apiId: "abc111i6h3",
      stage: "dev",
      throttle: {
        "/staff/list/GET": {
          burstLimit: 4,
          rateLimit: 8,
        },
      },
    },
  ]
```

Example from [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-usage-plans-with-rest-api.html) that gave that hint:
[image]